# top-level class without companion can only expand either into an eponymous class or into a block consisting in eponymous companions

Tags: scala, scala-cats, scala-macros

I am trying to use https://github.com/estatico/scala-newtype as follows:

```
import io.estatico.newtype.macros.newtype
import cats._
import io.databaker.env._

@newtype case class DbUrl(v: String)

@newtype case class DbUser(v: String)

@newtype case class DbPw(v: String)

final case class DbParams(url: DbUrl, user: DbUser, pw: DbPw)

trait DbConnector[F[_]] {
  def read(url: DbUrl, user: DbUser, pw: DbPw): F[DbParams]
}


object DbConnector {

  def impl[F[_] : MonadError[*[_], Throwable]](env: Environment[F])
  : DbConnector[F] =
    new LiveDbConnector[F](env)

}
```

and the compiler complains:

```
[error] ../db/DbConnector.scala:7:2: top-level class without companion can only expand either into an eponymous class or into a block consisting in eponymous companions
[error] @newtype case class DbUrl(v: String)
[error]  ^
[error] ../db/DbConnector.scala:9:2: top-level class without companion can only expand either into an eponymous class or into a block consisting in eponymous companions
[error] @newtype case class DbUser(v: String)
[error]  ^
[error] ../db/DbConnector.scala:11:2: top-level class without companion can only expand either into an eponymous class or into a block consisting in eponymous companions
[error] @newtype case class DbPw(v: String)
[error]  ^
[error] ../env/Environment.scala:8:2: top-level class without companion can only expand either into an eponymous class or into a block consisting in eponymous companions
[error] @newtype case class EnvValue(v: String)
[error]  ^
[error] ../env/Environment.scala:6:2: top-level class without companion can only expand either into an eponymous class or into a block consisting in eponymous companions
[error] @newtype case class EnvVariable(v: String)
```

The content of the `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(JettyPlugin)
  .settings(
    organization := "io.example",
    name := "user-svc",
    version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
    scalaVersion := "2.13.2",
    mainClass := Some("io.example.Main"),
    containerPort := 9090,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.http4s" %% "http4s-servlet" % Http4sVersion,
      "org.http4s" %% "http4s-circe" % Http4sVersion,
      "org.http4s" %% "http4s-dsl" % Http4sVersion,
      "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % CirceVersion,
      "org.scalameta" %% "munit" % MunitVersion % "test",
      "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % LogbackVersion,
      "io.estatico" %% "newtype" % NewTypeVersion,
      "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % ServletVersion % "provided"
    ),
    addCompilerPlugin("org.typelevel" %% "kind-projector" % "0.11.0" cross CrossVersion.full),
    addCompilerPlugin("com.olegpy" %% "better-monadic-for" % "0.3.1"),
  )

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-deprecation",
  "-encoding", "UTF-8",
  "-language:higherKinds",
  "-language:postfixOps",
  "-feature",
  "-Xfatal-warnings",
  "-Ymacro-annotations"
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I have moved the **newtype** macros into package object as follows:

```
package object db {
  
  @newtype case class DbUrl(v: String)

  @newtype case class DbUser(v: String)

  @newtype case class DbPw(v: String)

}
```

but the compiler still complains:

```
implicit conversion method opsThis should be enabled
[error] by making the implicit value scala.language.implicitConversions visible.
[error]   @newtype case class DbUser(v: String)
```

Comment: According to the README.md: *"This expands into a type and companion object definition, so newtypes* must  *be defined in an object or package object."*

Comment: @user Actually here in `scala-newtype` this is inaccuracy in formulations. If somebody defines `type T; object T` then object `T` is not companion object of type `T`, it's just an object with the same name (eponymous). According to Scala [spec](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#object-definitions) an object can be companion only to classes and traits, not types. For example implicits defined inside object `T` will not be found for type `T` without imports etc.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Yeah, I guess they meant singleton object or something else? The generated type seems to be the type of the object itself (`type T = T.type`) and not the class/trait that the object is the companion of.

Comment: @user not `T.type` but `T.Type` (upper case), so this not the type of object itself.

Comment: @DmytroMitin My bad, I didn't read too closely. I'll fix that in my answer

Comment: The new error is just because of [this part](https://github.com/estatico/scala-newtype/blob/e49fcf3850b7a9e288e4115919d61bafbca53036/shared/src/main/scala/io/estatico/newtype/macros/NewTypeMacros.scala#L219). You just need to enable implicit conversions

Comment: How to enable implicit conversions ?

Comment: See the [docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-conversions.html). You can import `scala.language.implicitConversions` or use `-language:implicitConversions`

Comment: @user *Yeah, I guess they meant singleton object or something else?* I guess more correct is `object T` is an object from implicit scope of `type T`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [README.md](https://github.com/estatico/scala-newtype#newtype-macro) of scala-newtype says:

> This expands into a type and companion object definition, so newtypes *must* be defined in an object or package object.

Macros are allowed to expand classes into other classes with the same name and companion objects, but from what I can tell, the `newtype` annotation turns your `case class` into an object of the same name (along with a type alias like `type DbUrl = DbUrl.Type`). This behavior (turning a top-level annottee into a tree of some other kind) isn't allowed. If the annotation had generated a class `DbUrl`, and maybe an object of the same name, though, it would have been all right, but pretty much anything else won't work.

To fix your problem, all you need to do is move this into a package object (or some other scope, as long as it isn't top-level).

Edit: As Dmytro Mitin pointed out, the created type is not the type of `DbUrl` but rather something like `type DbUrl = DbUrl.Type` with an uppercase "T", where the definition of `DbUrl.Type` looks something like this (I'm just copying this from the README):

```
type Base = Any { type DbUrl$newtype }
trait Tag extends Any
type Type <: Base with Tag
```